# Redirect all calls to print to a file

Tags: python, file, printing

Consider this:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('Hola', file=f)
    print('voy', file=f)
    print('a', file=f)
    print('imprimir', file=f)
    print('muchas', file=f)
    print('líneas', file=f)
    print('acá', file=f)
```

Is it possible to avoid reference to `f` in each line? Something like:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_print_to(f):
        print('Hola')
        print('voy')
        print('a')
        print('imprimir')
        print('muchas')
        print('líneas')
        print('acá')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis looks like task for [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout), example usage

```
import contextlib
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        print('Hello')
        print('World')
        print('!')
```

**Warning**: requires `python3.4` or newer

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
# put your words in a list
lines = ['Hola', 'voy', 'a', 'imprimir', 'muchas', 'líneas', 'acá']

#open the file
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    # for each line in your list
    for item in lines:
        # write item to file
        f.write(item)
        # depending of in you want each word on a new line or not
        f.write('\n')
```

---

**Edit:** My first answer did not actually answer the real question. Yes, you do not need to reference `f`, even if this is a usual way to print to file. You can for example use `sys.stdout`. Here is an example of that:

```
import sys
lines = ['Hola', 'voy', 'a', 'imprimir', 'muchas', 'líneas', 'acá']

sys.stdout=open("file.txt","w")
for item in lines:
    print (item)
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: This does not avoid a reference to `f` in each line. It is the same...

Comment: @user171780 Sorry! Did not read careful enough. Maybe my edited answer is what you are looking for?